# Intellij IDEA 11: how can I compile .css from .less?

Tags: css, intellij-idea, less

how can I compile .css from .less in intellij ? sure this should be dead easy, but its got me stumped. anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA relies on web frameworks and third-party deployment tools to perform this task. There is a [feature request to perform such compilation internally](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-2900), feel free to vote.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote a [LESS Compiler plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pr=&pluginId=7059) that automatically compiles LESS files to CSS whenever they change.

You can configure multiple LESS directories to watch per project, and the output of each will be copied to one or more output CSS directories that you specify:

[image: LESS Compiler project settings window]

You can include / exclude specific files by using path patterns in the settings dialog.

It will also detect when you move, copy, or delete a watched LESS file and offer to perform the same operation on the corresponding CSS file(s).

The plugin is open source, so you can [view and fork the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/acdvorak/intellij-lessc-plugin) if you like.

Comment: thanks! working rather nicely. Don't see an option for watching all files, but only compiling some, but it's a good start.

Comment: That feature has been added since I posted the screenshot :-)  You can include and/or exclude specific files by specifying one or more path patterns in the LESS Compiler settings.  All LESS files in the watch directory are monitored, but the only ones that match the pattern(s) you specify are actually compiled.  That way you can make changes to an excluded file that other included files (i.e., its dependents) `@import`, and only the included files will be re-compiled.

Comment: thanks for clarifications. didn't know that.
However, there is still an issue. the project structure has the file which are to be compile in a separate directory. So it's:
less\includes less\main and less\config. 
When I ask it to only compile the files which are only in main, it does so, but creates a sub-directory of "main" in the output location

Comment: You're right - currently there's no way to do that.  The plugin always re-creates the full directory structure of the source LESS folder in the output directory.  Feel free to [create an issue in the issue tracker](https://github.com/acdvorak/intellij-lessc-plugin/issues) and I'll consider adding such a feature in the next version!

Answer (score 14):

To use File Watchers to compile LESS in IDEA 12:

Install **File Watchers** extension from within IDEA. Go to **Settings > IDE Settings > Plugins**.

Next you need a **transcoder**, which is included in the LESS package for node.js

Install **node.js** from http://nodejs.org/

From the command line, type **npm install -g less** to install the LESS package.

Then you can create a watcher under **Settings > Project Settings > File Watchers**. Choose the LESS template and it will find your transcoder automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is for IntelliJ IDEA 11, but if you found this page even though you're searching for v12, there's an option better than the LESS compiler plugin (which was a great plugin -- thanks a lot for it, Andy!).

It's a plugin called [File Watchers](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?webide&pluginId=7177), made by the JetBrains team. It comes bundled with WebStorm 6 and PhpStorm 6, but you have to download and install for the other JetBrians IDEs. Steps:

**Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories (button at the bottom) -> search for "file watchers" -> select File Watchers -> click download icon at top -> Close -> OK**

More info on [JetBrains blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a File Watcher with the following parameters:

> Name: LESS
>
> Description: Compiles .less files into .css files
>
> File Type: LESS files
>
> Scope: Project Files
>
> Program: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd
>
> Arguments: --no-color $FileDir$\$FileName$
>
> Working Directory: your working directory
>
> Output Paths to Refresh: $FileDir$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css