# Configuring Intellij-Idea to find css files

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I've been using Grails with the new assets-pipeline plugin and I've realized that now that my css has moved from web-app/css to grails-app/assets/stylesheets, Idea no longer does any css completion and can no longer go to class definitions.

I'm sure that I'm missing something.  I've tried adding extra source folders to the project pointed at the new assets folder, I've tried it as a resources folder. I've tried adding it as a web resources folder.  Nothing seems to work.  More to the point the documentation on this is so self referential that it's only really useful if you know the answer in the first place.

So, given that I've now got my css under grails-app/assets/stylesheets, how do I configure my Idea project so that it knows that it can find my project css here?

Comment: have a look over [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844342/intellij-idea-11-how-can-i-compile-css-from-less)

Comment: I have this same problem. I appreciate that Idea auto complete css and image files. Do you solved this?